# Running python script on webpage

Tags: python

I have a python script that takes in a .csv file and performs some data cleaning and some more advanced operations and gives back a .csv file as its output.

Is there a library I can use to build a webpage and host it on some server for users to be able to upload the input .csv file into it and be able to download the output .csv file?

Comment: Search for `flask`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would say your best choice if you are new to web development, is to start learning `Flask` and the basics of *"How the Web Works"*. There are other libraries such as Django or Cherrypy as well. Flask is a web framework that can run a server side application (a.k.a. *back-end*) and it's relatively simple out of the box.

However, when you say "running python script on webpage" and "build a webpage", that's not exactly how it works. You will build your *webpage* (a.k.a. the *client-side application* or the *front-end*) using HTML, CSS and possibly JavaScript. Web browsers can't run python.